# Add a custom function to setInterval in jquery

Tags: jquery

i tried everything i can imagine, but i can't get this to work... I created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DftyD/3/ (its not working there)

I want to execute my moveit-function constantly on mouseover (if i do it on mousemove, i have a problem when the gallery resizes on click)

```
cont.bind('mouseenter', function() {
    active = setInterval(moveit, 20);  // WHAT IS WRONG HERE?
        }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    active && clearInterval(active);
});

function moveit(e) {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var contWidth = cont.width();
    var galWidth = lastImg[0].offsetLeft + lastImg.outerWidth();
    var left = (e.pageX - cont.offset().left) * (galWidth - contWidth) / contWidth;
    cont.scrollLeft(left);
};
```

i'm new to jquery, so my code is a littlebit messy. Hope you understand my problem and maybe can help me.

thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event when doing it that way, otherwise `e.pageX` is undefined inside `moveit()`:

```
var active;

cont.on({
    mouseenter : function(event) {
        active = setInterval(function() {
            moveit(event);
        }, 20);
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        clearInterval(active);
    }
});
```

of course, that would make the value of `e.pageX` the same as when the mouse entered the element, it won't update for each interval iteration, so it only moves once.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DftyD/4/)

Comment: Great, thankyou very much adeneo!!! that goes in the right direction, but i thought that would trigger my function constantly, but it does it only once ... am i on the wrong way?

Comment: It does trigger the function constantly, but the value of `event.pageX` is always the same, so nothing moves.

Comment: i see... can you give me a hint how to do it then? ... sorry, i'm new to this and don't have any idea :(

Comment: @SandyMaier - something like this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DftyD/5/) I assume ?

Comment: i would like to achive an effect like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DftyD/6/ ....the only problem is that the gallery should stay at the same position when clicking it, what doesn't work if i do it on mousemove. understand what i mean..? thanks :)

Comment: Not sure how you'd figure that out, but the effect you're after should and probably will have to be made with mousemove, as you can't really emulate that with an interval.